# Is $\int_{0}^{x}{|\sin t|dt}$ asymptotically equivalent to $2x$?

Tags: limits

Or to what? For $x\to+\infty$.

In the previous question, I wrote

$lim_{x->+\infty}{\int_{0}^{x}|\sin t|dt=\sum_{1}^{+\infty}{2}=lim_{n->+\infty}{2n}=+\infty}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $N$ supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, I meant x.

Comment: What have you tried? Any thoughts as to how to proceed?

Comment: What's the definition of asymptotically equivalent here? Is it that the ratio goes to $1$, or that one is Big Theta ($\Theta$) of the other? Anyway, I think, considering you produced that $2$, that you have forgotten to take the period into account...maybe you are thinking of a result that you found for a function with period $1$.

Comment: just split the integral $[0,n\pi]\cup[n\pi,x]$.

Comment: I thought 2x because the limit produces the sum from 1 to +inf of 2.

Comment: It stays within a bounded distance from $\frac{2x}{\pi}$, if that's what you mean.

Comment: And if you split it like @zwim suggested, you can compute the bound.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, if you call $\begin{cases}n=\lfloor \frac x{\pi}\rfloor & n\in\mathbb Z\\r=x-n\pi & r\in[0,\pi)\end{cases}$

$$I(x)=\int_0^x|\sin(t)|dt=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|\sin(t)|dt+\int_{n\pi}^x|\sin(t)|dt$$

The integral on $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$ is constant of value $2$.

The integral on $[n\pi,x]$ is $\displaystyle \int_{n\pi}^{n\pi+r}|\sin(t)|dt=\int_0^r|\sin(t)|dt=1-\cos(r)$

Therefore $$I(x)=2n+1-\cos(r)$$

Now you can reintroduce $x$ to get $I(x)=2\dfrac{x-r}{\pi}+1-\cos(r)=\dfrac{2x}{\pi}+\underbrace{\bigg(1-\dfrac{2r}{\pi}-\cos(r)\bigg)}_\text{bounded}$

The last part is bounded because $r\in[0,\pi)$ and $|\cos(r)|\le 1$, thus $I(x)\sim \dfrac{2x}{\pi}$

Note:

*it is not mandatory to get the exact expression for $I(x)$, you can say that $\int_0^r|\sin(t)|dt\le\int_0^\pi|\sin(t)|dt\le 2$ for the same conclusion (bounded)*

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Could I also say that the integral of a periodic function is asymptotically equivalent to x over half the period?

Comment: the $2$ is not half the period, it is the value of integral. $\int_0^xf(t)dt\sim x\times\frac 1T\int_0^Tf(t)dt$ for $f$ periodic of period $T$.

Comment: Perfect, I will use this. Is the limit correct instead?